# Flow: Overriding attribute with spread operator in object literal

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am rewriting the optional type with exact value:

```
/* @flow */

type A = {
  attr: ?string
}

type B = {
  attr: string 
}

const func = (a: A): B => ({
    ...a,
    attr: "someString",
})
```

Why is Flow complaining?

```
11: const func = (a: A): B => ({                               ^ Cannot return object literal because null or undefined [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `attr`.
References:
4:   attr: ?string           ^ [1]
8:   attr: string 
           ^ [2]
```

[Live code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN6phgCGGGATgFxgD8AzowJYB2A5qgC+6bPjAAhUhSq16zMJwa8+YIegDGcHpzBQArj3VSAFDRaEAlC0kkAfGGOUAkADo3NADQy6jFgCJ2OABbPABlbn4-L0ELGSA)

Comment: This will no longer be an error as of Flow v0.111.0! Some major changes to spread are coming out with that version. You can see this now by changing the version in flow.org/try to "master"